# Remove space for horizontal scroll bar

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling

I am adding tablerows dynamically in table layout.When I am using both vertical and horizontal scroll bar.Due to horizontal scroll I am getting some space in my layout. My xml file is-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:scrollbars="none">

         <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:scrollbars="none">

<TableLayout 
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:id="@+id/main_table" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent">


</TableLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>







</LinearLayout>
```

Screenshot is-

[image]

I want to remove that space from right side.

Comment: have you tried `android:layout_weight="wrap_content"` for your `TableLayout `

Comment: Anushka, I think you have to set layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: plz post your layout row xml file

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal,@pratik-I have tried it but its not working.Its still taking space in right side.

Comment: @DigveshPatel-I am adding table rows dynamically not through xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Simple change

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scrollbars="none">

     <HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scrollbars="none">
```

to this

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scrollbars="none">

     <HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scrollbars="none">
```

Comment: (So change wrap_content to match_parent for the width)

Comment: @Kostya Khuta- Its not working.Still its taking that space in right side.

Comment: is it your whole xml file?

Comment: @KostyaKhuta-I have other xml in which I am setting viewpager.Its not connected with this.